# Labels showing for form multiple check box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I'm creating a form with multiple check-boxes, the options being a list of user roles, with my view as follows:

```
        <% roles = User.roles %>
        <% roles.each do |role| %>
          <%= f.label roles.each do %>
            <%= f.check_box :role, { multiple: true }, role, nil %>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
```

The issue I am having is that the check boxes are being created, and the correct User role correspond to each checkbox (as confirmed by using Developer Tools), but I cannot get labels to show up next to the check boxes.

The output of User.roles is as follows:

```
{"admin"=>0, "developer_admin"=>1, "division_admin"=>2, "development_admin"=>3, "site_admin"=>4}
```

What obvious thing am I overlooking here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me as if the issue is corrected by the below change:

**Changes based on your recent update: `User.roles` is a hash which we destructure and pass in as follows:**

```
    <% roles = User.roles %>
    <% roles.each do |name, value| %>
      #                v here v
      <%= f.label :role, name %>
      <%= f.check_box :role, { multiple: true }, value, nil %>
    <% end %>
```

You're likely passing an `Enumerator`  to the label, rather than the role itself. Try calling `User.roles.each` in the console without a block, you'll get something like: `#<Enumerator: ...>`.

As a quick side note, it's preferable to carry out assignment outside of the view: you'd be better placed assigning `@roles = User.roles` in your controller, and using the instance variable in your view.

Hope that helps - let me know how you get on.

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly. The model I am using to create the check-boxes is User, with role being a column on the user model. With the change above, I get the following error: 
undefined method `name' for ["admin", 0]:Array

Comment: Welcome @DevCF :) Could you do me a favour and edit your question to include the output of `User.roles` please? Drop me a comment when done and I'll update my answer.

Comment: Saying that, I've taken a punt based on what you've shown in your comment. The above may now work, though I can clarify when you've update the question.

Comment: Thanks, I've included the output of User.roles. I tried updating my code as per your suggestion but still no luck, the labels are not showing (but nothing is breaking which is a positive at least?).

Comment: Thanks for the update @DevCF - try the above, that should work for you :)

Answer (score 0):

My code is like SRack answers, but I've adjusted it for the hash output and edited the role name, so we can click on the text and it will activate the option :)

```rb
<% User.roles.each do |name, value| %>
  <%= f.label "role_#{value}" do %>
    <%= f.check_box :role, { multiple: true }, value, nil %>
    <%= name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```